# Compute the similarity between two txt.files

Tags: python, text

I have two text files with different words. The important thing is, that the text files just contain words and no sentences. 
So the first file could look like this: `xyz, acbe, eidjh, eheha.`

I want to compute the similarity between these two text files. I would like to display the result by a % rate, but also by which words this similarity results.

I read about the cosine similarity but I am not sure if this is applicable for my problem!

Comment: What have you tried so far? And what do you mean by similarity? Are you trying to count how many words are the same or what else?

Comment: Yes actually I want to count how many words are the same. I have tried it with same=set(file1).intersection(file2) and then write the results in a output text file. However, with the intersection I just get the words who are the same

Comment: Are there repetitions of words in each file or is every word unique?

Comment: There are repetitions of words in each file. Only some words are unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution would be, after having read the files and split them into words, to just cycle through them, first assigning them to a dictionary to count the number of occurences per file, then calculate the relative ratios, check which words appear in both and compute the final rate:

```
temp1 = open('yourfile1.txt')
file1 = temp1.read().split(',')
temp1.close()
temp2 = open('yourfile2.txt')
file2 = temp2.read.split(',')
dict1 = {x : file1.count(x) for x in file1}
dict2 = {x : file2.count(x) for x in file2}
similars = set(file1).intersection(set(file2))
rate1 = sum(dict1[w] for w in similars)/len(file1)
rate2 = sum(dict2[w] for w in similars)/len(file2)
print("The rate of similarity is: ", rate1*rate2*100, '%')
print("The similar words are: ", similars)
```

Where of course `yourfile1.txt` and `yourfile2.txt` are the names of your files.